# Why setSkew increase text size?

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText version 5.2.1.
To fully understand the `setSkew` method of `Chunk` object, i began to play with it with the following code:

```
  for (int i=0; i <= 90; i+=5) {
    Chunk c = new Chunk("A" + i);
    c.setSkew((float)i, (float)-i);
    document.add(c);
  }
```

With my big surprise the text progressively gets bigger when approaching to 90 degree. I can't understand this behaviour: according to "itext in action 2nd ed." book, the first parameter of setSkew is the inclination of the baseline of the text, and the second the angle between characters and the (original) baseline.

So, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing essentially is that you expect the skewing with your parameters to be merely something like a simple rotation which would keep sizes as they are. This is **not** the case for skewing. Instead skewing works like this:

[image: sketch explaining skewing]

*(shamelessly copied out of "Figure 13 – Effects of Coordinate Transformations" in the [PDF specification ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

What remains the same is the length of the *projection* of the skewed base line onto the regular base line of the text line:

[image: sketch with baseline projections x0 and x1]

Here x0 and x1 have the same length, but the skewed base line is longer. The steeper the angle is, the longer is the skewed base line and also the width of the glyphs there.

The analog goes for the y axis. Thus, your sample results in something like this:

[image]

If you prefer a mathematical reasoning, consider that the skewing transformation matrix has the values [1 tan(a) tan(b) 1 0 0]. So (1, 0) is skewed to (1, tan(a)), (0, 1) to (tan(b), 1), and everything else correspondignly according to linearity.